# Avoiding special characters in the XML output using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am reading tweets and forming an XML out of it, for which I am using JAXB Marshaller and UTF-8 encoding.

JAXB Marshaller setting is:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext;
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(obj.getClass());
Marshaller m = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();  
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
m.marshal(obj, writer);
```

Here, `obj` is my class object which contains tweet text and other information.

My problem is, the generated XML contains special characters like:

```
> x85, x93, xAQ
```

Sample Output XML:

```
   <tweet>
        <id>500923859663872000</id>
        <createdAt>2014-08-17T14:05:29+05:30</createdAt>
        **<text>Ԁhughwizzy: 55% of all '14-'15 @PremierLeague players will wear @Nike** Boots. (@adidas 35%, @Puma 5%). http://t.co/VHit1Es7KlԠ@Yup_Yup9</text>
        <langISOCode>en</langISOCode>
        <place>NA</place>
        <favouriteCount>0</favouriteCount>
        <retweetCount>0</retweetCount>
        <isPossiblySensitive>false</isPossiblySensitive>
        <user>
            <id>39481349</id>
            <createdAt>2009-05-12T17:12:37+05:30</createdAt>
            <location>NA</location>
            <followersCount>281</followersCount>
            <listedCount>4</listedCount>
            <preferredLang>en</preferredLang>
            <isVerified>false</isVerified>
            <isTranslator>false</isTranslator>
        </user>
    </tweet>
```

I found that these are UTF-8 encoded characters, but it makes my XML invalid.

Is there a way to avoid these characters in the generated XML.

Comment: Unless you do something weird, you can't produce characters with invalid encoding. In Java, you have String (and char) values, and the XML Writer uses the marshaller's setting to produce the encoded output. You'll have to provide more information for advice about what needs to be done, what may have gone wrong etc. What is the String value/unicode code point that produces those "invalid" characters?

Comment: Hi Laune, I have added my marshaller settings above. Before this, I am just reading the text out of the Twitter API and setting it to my object's field using the setter method.

Comment: That's not enough. Provide the field of `obj` that produces the "invalid" characters. Why do you think that they are invalid? What is the XML like? The hex values you are showing don't make up an UTF-8 encoded character. -- Do you want this cleared up or not?

Comment: I have added a tweet element of the output XML. The text element's value contains some invalid character, which is making the whole XML invalid. Do I need to change the encoding to something else? Or is there any other library which takes care of all the special characters?

Comment: There is no `<?xml ... encoding...?>`?? Did you suppress it?

Comment: This looks as if the source data for element <text> hasn't been received/transferred correctly; I think that already the STring text property within the tweet object is corrupt. You could verify this by printing this field before you marshal. (Make sure your environment renders these characters correctly, *or* print a sequence of char values as intergers (in hex).

Comment: I checked, this is exactly what the user has tweeted. I am not changing anything there. Also, XML declaration is present in the output. User can enter any special character in the tweet. Is there a way to handle that? Is there any other library which takes care of all the special characters?

Comment: Well, if the original user has tweeted that, it is what you want to have in the XML as well, don't you?? What **is** the XML declaration? What does encoding= say??

Comment: XML Declaration is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>. I actually want the original text, but at the same time I need to display it on browser and allow it to read by other XML parsers.

Comment: Now really! You have `Ԁ` (U+0500 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER KOMI DE character) in this XML file, absolutely correctly encoded in UTF-8 (as indicated by the encoding in the XML declararion) as the sequence of two bytes: 0xD4, 0x80, and the other chararcter is correctly encoded as well. You say that this is the correct, original text, so it is fine. Any programs handling XML correctly will be able to process it. Who or what says that your XML is invalid?

Comment: I am not able to open it in browser. After I remove these characters, I am able to do so.

Comment: This is a problem of your browser, not of JAXB or whatsoever else. I can open it (Firefox 31.0), and the characters appear exactly as displayed here in your question.

Comment: Even I am using the same browser. But if I am using UTF-8 encoding I am getting some characters like 'x85', which is making the xml invalid to be rendered by the browser correctly.  I tried pasting that character above but somehow the symbol represented by it is getting displayed there.

Comment: There is none of these bytes \x85, \x93, \xA0 in the XML file as you have posted it. - What do you mean by "if I am using UTF-8 encoding"? You don't have a choice, because it *is* UTF-8 encoded. - What do you mean by "I tried ... displayed there." - I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) wikipedia page says HTML 4 DTDs define 252 named entities and if we want to use one of these character entity references in an HTML or XML document, we have to enter an ampersand followed by the entity name and a semicolon, e.g., &amp;. I believe this is what I have to handle manually in my code, as it is not handled by JAXB internally.

Comment: Entities like `&amp;` would be handled automatically if there were any necessity of it. - If your environment can't handle UTF-8 encoding, set the encoding to US-ASCII: `marshaller.setProperty( "jaxb.encoding", "US-ASCII" )`

Comment: Its able to handle &amp; but if there is a symbol like  copyright symbol or currency sign in the tweet text, these symbols are not handled by jaxb. My issue is with these symbols.

Comment: I give up. Did you try US-ASCII?

Comment: I tried but no luck with it. Anyways thanks Laune, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Since by setting the US-ASCII encoding all non-ASCII characters are represented as `&xxx` (Did you see that?) thi proves that you won't achieve your goal by fiddling with JAXB, by manually changing characters to entities or some other desperate hack. - Read the w3c tutorials on XML, and the XML spec itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can Base64Encode the string before you set it to your variable in your object. If you want to display the content in the browser you can extract the xml value for that *text*, then you can display after decoding it.

```
obj.setText(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(byte[] your_tweet_as_a_byte_array));
// serialize it
//in the front end extract the xml value for your text using javascript. lets say xml contains like this:=>  <text>adiufgdb12bsre==<text>
// you can use the following code in the javascript to decode it.
atob(extracted_encoded _string) // will give you the decoded string.
```

Using this way you can avoid creating an invalid xml, by avoiding xml not supported unicode characters.